# IEEE Std 754 Floating-Point: let t := a - b, does the standard guarantee that a == b + t?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, ieee-754

Assume that `t`,`a`,`b` are all double (IEEE Std 754) variables, and both values of `a`, `b` are NOT `NaN` (but may be `Inf`).
After `t = a - b`, do I necessarily have `a == b + t`?

Comment: I believe the result of an underflow there would be undefined, and so would that of an overflow in the second expression, so no. If someone could confirm that, it'd be nice.

Comment: Ah, I guess this kind of confirms that overflow is undefined for floating-point too: `As
with any other arithmetic overﬂow, if the result does not ﬁt in the space provided, the behavior is undeﬁned.`

Comment: In a C implementation conforming to IEEE 754, there is no UB for any floating point arithmetic. All results are strictly defined.

Comment: @R.., thanks. I don't have that particular version available and that text is what was in mine.

Comment: If a=b=Inf then t=NaN and the second equation fails. You can probably find another example using negative zero.

Comment: C allows a lot (some would say *complete*, i.e. results can be completely meaningless) leeway in what floating point does in a non-IEEE-conforming implementation. In reality, most real-world implementations that people care about purport to conform to IEEE 754. The text governing normative behavior for C implementations aiming to support IEEE arithmetic is in Annex F of the C standard.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Negative zero is a great example too, but see my answer for some less obscure cases...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Absolutely not. One obvious case is `a=DBL_MAX`, `b=-DBL_MAX`. Then `t=INFINITY`, so `b+t` is also `INFINITY`.

What may be more surprising is that there are cases where this happens without any overflow. Basically, they're all of the form where `a-b` is inexact. For example, if `a` is `DBL_EPSILON/4` and `b` is `-1`, `a-b` is 1 (assuming default rounding mode), and `a-b+b` is then 0.

The reason I mention this second example is that this is the *canonical* way of forcing rounding to a particular precision in IEEE arithmetic. For instance, if you have a number in the range [0,1) and want to force rounding it to 4 bits of precision, you would add and then subtract `0x1p49`.

Comment: The 2nd example is great as it doesn't incur Inf nor NaN. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You might want to clarify the `0x1p49` constant, the last time I looked hex digits ran from 0 to F ;)

Comment: @MSalters: "0x1p49" is hexadecimal floating-point, as defined in the C standard. The format is "0x" <significand> "p" <exponent>, where <significand> is a hexadecimal numeral, optionally including a period, and <exponent> is a decimal numeral, optionally including a sign. The base for the exponent is two, so 0x1p49 is 2**49. 0x1p-4 would be 1/16, and 0x1.23p8 would be (1 + 2/16 + 3/256) * 2**8 = 291. Hexadecimal floating-point provides a format that is easy for humans and compilers to convert to and from binary floating-point encodings without rounding issues.

Answer (score 1):

In the process of doing the first operation, bits could have been lost off the low end of the result.  So one question is, will the second operation exactly reproduce those losses?  I haven't fully thought that out.

But, of course, the first operation could have overflowed to +/-infinity, rendering the second compare unequal.

(And, of course, in the general case using `==` for floating-point values is almost always a bug.)

Comment: Just by a counting argument, the second operation can't bring back what was lost. If it could, you'd be storing more bits of information in `t` than the number of bits in `t`...

Comment: @R -- Yes.  Intuitively one knows that it won't work, because of what you say, but finding examples is better "proof" than appealing to an esoteric rule, no matter how valid.

Answer (score -3):

You are not guaranteed anything when using floats. If the exponent is different for both numbers, the result of an arithmetic operation may not be completely representable in a float.

Consider this code:

```
float a = 0.003f;
float b = 10000000.0f;
float t = a - b;
float x = b + t;
```

Running on Visual Studio 2010, you get `t==-10000000.0f`, and therefore `x==0`.

You should never use equality when comparing floats. Instead compare the absolute value of the difference between both values and an epsilon value small enough for your precision needs.

It gets even weirder as different floating point implementations may return different results for the same operation.

Comment: I never liked the "compare the absolute value of the difference" advice.  It is possible to get bounds on errors ([What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) is a good start) and one should think about what one is trying to accomplish with the comparison before blindly switching to some arbitrary bound.

Comment: There are plenty of things that are guaranteed when using IEEE-754 floats.  This happens to not be one of them.

Comment: There are lots of guarantees when using IEEE floats, and there are times when comparing for equality is not only reasonable, but essential. Floating-point math is definitely tricky, but it isn't random or malicious. Here's an example from my blog of when testing for floating-point equality is critical: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/01/27/theres-only-four-billion-floatsso-test-them-all/